# Finding external functions in LLVM

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to write an LLVM pass that will find functions that call external functions (i.e. ones that are not defined in the current compilation unit) either directly or indirectly

For example, when run on the C following code:

`void a(string s) {print(s)};
int b(int x) {return 1}
void c(void) {a("hello);b}`

It should flag up a and c.

I need some way of telling if a given call inst corresponds to a direct call to an external function. My first approach was extracting the function object from the call inst, then using the isDeclaration() method inherited from the GlobalValue class. This ended up returning true on every function call, which is obviously not desirable.

What is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Using `isDeclaration` is right. I just tried this out and it definitely doesn't return true for every call. Can you post the specific code you're using, and the code you ran it on?

Comment: It'll depend very specifically on the version of LLVM you're using.